# Did a git stash - had unstaged changes, is there a way to reverse that?

Tags: git, git-stash, git-stage

i did a git stash and had some changes that were not added to the index, when i did a git stash apply, they were not reapplied. Is there a way to get back from this?

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: When you stash something (without --keep-index), all changes to existing files are saved, whether or not they have been staged. What exactly happened?

Comment: thanks for your comment. i needed to fix some bugs, so i did a git stash, then i pulled, pushed my commit, did git stash apply and then my changes were gone and not reapplied..? Any ideas..?

Comment: Show the output from `git stash apply`.

Comment: Sounds like a merge conflict. You'll have to resolve the conflict and then drop the stash if that's the case. As Roman said, the output would tell you this.

Comment: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
 app/.meteor/versions
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting

Comment: Ahhh ok i kind of didnt see that - thanks for the help!